# Plugin with own library kills Browser

Tags: cmake, firebreath

I am new to C++ and plugin development. I am working with/for Unix and for the Firefox browser. So here we go:
I have a plugin which uses some classes from a own library. The problem is: it kills my browser asap. I cant even start my browser as soon as MyPlugin.so is in the plugin folder of the Firefox. The library is build and doesn't kill a desktop application that uses it.
My guess is that I failed at linking my library with CMake or forgot to include some stuff from FireBreath. So here are the two things I assume are wrong, maybe someone can help me out.

1) (wrong?) linking with Cmake:
I added some of these at the end of the **CMakeLists.txt** of my project. The paths are where the library is.

```
    add_definitions(-L${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../lib/bin)
    add_definitions(-I${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../lib/src)
    add_definitions(-lcoala64) [name of the library]
    add_definitions(-Wl,-rpath=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../lib/bin)
    add_definitions(-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0)
```

And used the prepmake.sh to generate my build files. Then I followed up with adding flags manually (because I dont know a better solution) to the in the /buid/projects/MyPlugin/CMakeFiles/MyPlugin.dir/**link.txt**

```
    -L/home/username/swp/dev/lib/bin
    -I/home/username/swp/dev/lib/src
    -lcoala64 -Wl,-rpath=/home/username/swp/dev/lib/bin
```

Afterwards I could build the plugin. It builds, so one could assume I have linked correctly. But said crashes appear as soon as I want to use it.

2) Do I use the library wrong?
I include like this in MyPluginAPI.h:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
    #include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
    #include "JSAPIAuto.h"
    #include "BrowserHost.h"
    #include "X11/X11KryptoKoala.h"
    //Include from my own library:
    #include "../../../lib/src/Key.hpp"
```

As soon as I add the following line to MyPlugin.cpp I get the mentioned crashes while the same line works without a problem in the desktop application that uses the same library:

```
    Key key(password_);
```

Now I hope this isn't a too big wall of text and someone is willing to investigate and answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use add_definitions() in that way. CMake allows to differentiate your directives in different categories, so that they only go in the necessary command line. You should use:

```
 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pthread")
 include_directories(/usr/include/gtk-2.0  
                     /usr/include/cairo
                     etc. etc.
                    )
 add_library(the_name_of_your_target gtk-x11-2.0 gdk-x11-2.0 ETC. ETC.)
 link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../lib/bin)
```

Furthermore, there are FindPackage functionalities that can help you setting automatically variables containing the name of your libraries, their directories, their include path.

Most information can be found [here](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html) and [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables)

Then: What is then prepmake.sh? Are you running cmake at all? Can you use cmake-gui, and then select one canonical build system, like make or ninja?

Finally: It could be that you have a crash because your library are not in your library path. I assume you are under linux, here are some ideas: [LD_LIBRARY_PATH vs LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250624/ld-library-path-vs-library-path) and [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830542/ld-library-path)

Comment: to clarify, prepmake.sh is just a helper that calls cmake to do an out of source build; we use it to help people not familiar with cmake to not shoot themselves in the foot as quickly

Comment: Yeah; I started that before I myself was fully familiar with cmake, and I'd love to change a lot of things, but simply don't have time

Comment: Hey, thanks for the ideas. Sadly it didnt help at all. I did what you suggested and checked with ldd if my plugin links my library to the correct path and it did. I guess the PluginContainer of FireFox doesnt like it or something.