# Cannot use 'cp' to copy the file libstdc++.so.6.0.21 using terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, anaconda, command

I was trying to copy and paste the file named `libstdc++.so.6.0.2` from

/home/a11111/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21 on linux

using the command

```
cp ~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21 /lib64/
```

However, the terminal keep returning me the error message

```
'cp: cannot stat '/home/a11111/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21': No such file or directory'
```

I thought the terminal might not able to find the file because the file name has special characters, therefore I tried

```
cp ~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc\+\+\.so\.6\.0\.21 /lib64/
```

But I got the same error message. How do I copy the file from the terminal?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of escaping you can just use quotes around the name. Obviously, you know that this file exists in the filesystem, correct? What is the output of `ls "~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc*"`?

Comment: the output includes the filename that I am looking for "/home/a11111/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21", so why can't i copy it?

Comment: I also tried  'cp ~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc* /lib64/',   the terminal tell me that 'cp: cannot stat '/home/a1796450/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21': No such file or directory ' and 'cp: cannot create regular file '/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.22': Permission denied'

Comment: see instead https://stackoverflow.com/q/830542/1216776

Answer (score 0):

Just add double quotes around the filename:

```sh
cp "~/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.21" /lib64/
```

NB: You probably will need `sudo` in front of it because `/lib64` is owned by `root`

Comment: what can I do if I do not have permission to perform sudo operation? I am using ssh(Secure Shell Protocol).

Comment: Then you cannot copy the file to `/lib64`

Comment: You probably need libstdc++.so.6.0.21 to run some program. The new `libstdc++.so.6.0.21 <- libstdc++.so.6` can have any location in /home/[name]. ..... Run a program: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=new-location:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && start-command`